# MySQL database help: How do I find X in every column and delete it?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, sql-update, sql-like

for example I have a website with table website_info

and in it, I have these columns

(just some random image I found online) this photo

[image]

regarding the photo, how would I find the words "weight" and also "price" in "meta_key" (which is the middle column) and delete every entry?

Answer (score 4):

Use [**LIKE**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/pattern-matching.html) operator to search for specific keyword.

Try this:

```
DELETE FROM website_info 
WHERE meta_key LIKE '%_weight%' OR meta_key LIKE '%_price%';
```

To remove full keyword from the table use below query:

```
UPDATE website_info 
SET meta_key = ''
WHERE meta_key LIKE '%_weight%' OR meta_key LIKE '%_price%';
```

Comment: hey thanks but I dont want to delete the entire row, JUST the keywords in that row

Comment: @user5706585 You want to delete full keyword or part of it of matching row??

Comment: @user5706585 You're most welcome. If you get the desired result then you can accept the answer which fulfill your requirement